# Getting REST-ful URIs in Joomla?

Tags: rest, joomla

Using my own Joomla 1.5 component, module, or plugin, how would I turn a request for a REST URL like `foo.com/api/...` into relevant echo()s on the page? I'm looking for a "hello, world"-level example, if possible.

For example, `foo.com/api/baskets/10/fruits/list.json` might result in something like the following text on the page:

```
-- resource: baskets [id: 10]
-- resource: fruits [id: -]
-- action: list
-- format: json
```

Is that possible?

Comment: As an aside, the notion that hierarchical route-based URIs are essential for REST is overhyped IMO. They are certainly less important than statelessness, uniform interface, and hypertext. If your system is otherwise RESTful don't beat yourself up over wanting pretty URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read up on [Routing](http://docs.joomla.org/Routing).

Without the SEF options, you would simply link to something like the URL below, then in your controller, you'd check for the parameters:

```
index.php?option=com_example&baskets=10&action=list&formaat=json
```

With SEF turned on you can control the appearance of the URLs (aka "slugs) via routing.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there's nothing currently available that does this. However, between the `JRequest`, `JURI`, and `JDocument` classes, you should be able to build a RESTful interface for a component.